# how to use inner's result in outer function in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

currently,i learn node-mysql in node.js,but I meet a question,try a lot,i don't how to solve it ?

like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysqlcon=require('./testmysql');
var mysqlconn=mysqlcon.conn;
var http=require("http");
var url=require("url");
app.use('/sql',testExist).listen(3000);
function testExist(req,res,next){
    var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    var name=query.name;
    mysqlconn.connect();
    var result=function(err, results){
    return results.length;
    }
   mysqlconn.query('select * from  user where name = ?',[name],result);
   mysqlconn.end();
   if(result>1)
      console.log('result:'+result)
   res.end("name is already exist!")
}
```

I want to get the inner function's result in outer function ,for example the length of such query will be 1(results.length==1),but i want to use the result in testExist(),we know that node use callback function,so that i can't get the inner result in outer function.  So can any guys help me to solve it.

Comment: The result is async.  It happens sometime in the future AFTER the outer function has finished.  So, the answer to your question is you can't.  You have to change the structure of the code that uses the answer to put it inside the inner function or in a function you call from inside the inner function.

Comment: yes ,i know. it's async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need move the using code inside the callback.

```
function callback(err, results) {
  if(results.length >1) console.log('result:' + results.length);
  res.end("name is already exists!");
}
mysqlconn.query("select * from user where name= ?", [name], callback);
```